# Compiling a C++ program which uses sfml with mingw to port from linux to windows

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, libraries, sfml

I've messed with libraries a lot while trying to compile a simple program (main.cpp) which uses sfml but it doesn't compile. I'm really confused with mingw; how does mingw use gcc (g++ in this case) and how does it use the libraries?

**Check this out:**

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o app.exe main.cpp -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdint:41:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:420,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdint.h:124:27: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long unsigned int uintptr_t’
 typedef unsigned long int uintptr_t;
                           ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stddef.h:7:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/wchar.h:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/crtdefs.h:75:44: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef long long unsigned int uintptr_t’
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef unsigned __int64 uintptr_t;
                                            ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sec_api/stdlib_s.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:694,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:63:5: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct div_t div_t’
   } div_t;
     ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:62:5: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct _div_t div_t’
   } div_t;
     ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sec_api/stdlib_s.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:694,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:71:5: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct ldiv_t ldiv_t’
   } ldiv_t;
     ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:67:5: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct _ldiv_t ldiv_t’
   } ldiv_t;
     ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sec_api/stdlib_s.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:694,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:83:5: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct lldiv_t lldiv_t’
   } lldiv_t;
     ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:653:61: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct lldiv_t lldiv_t’
   typedef struct { __MINGW_EXTENSION long long quot, rem; } lldiv_t;
                                                             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:291:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sec_api/stdlib_s.h:9,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:694,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:109:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __ssize_t ssize_t’
 typedef __ssize_t ssize_t;
                   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stddef.h:7:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/wchar.h:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/crtdefs.h:45:35: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef long long int ssize_t’
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 ssize_t;
                                   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:130:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:291,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sec_api/stdlib_s.h:9,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:694,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/time_t.h:8:18: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __time_t time_t’
 typedef __time_t time_t;
                  ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stddef.h:7:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/wchar.h:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/crtdefs.h:138:20: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef __time64_t time_t’
 typedef __time64_t time_t;
                    ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sec_api/stdlib_s.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:694,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:555:12: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘int putenv(char*)’
 extern int putenv (char *__string) __THROW __nonnull ((1));
            ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:639:15: note: previous declaration ‘int putenv(const char*)’
   int __cdecl putenv(const char *_EnvString) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
               ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:856:0,
                 from /usr/include/malloc.h:24,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:695,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sys_errlist.h:27:38: error: conflicting declaration ‘const char* const _sys_errlist []’
 extern const char *const sys_errlist[];
                                      ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cstdlib:75:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h:164:38: note: previous declaration as ‘char* _sys_errlist [1]’
   extern __declspec(dllimport) char *_sys_errlist[1];
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cwctype:50:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/locale_facets.h:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/wctype.h:52:27: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long unsigned int wctype_t’
 typedef unsigned long int wctype_t;
                           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stddef.h:7:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/wchar.h:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3-win32/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/System.hpp:34,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/crtdefs.h:107:24: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef short unsigned int wctype_t’
 typedef unsigned short wctype_t;
```

It required files from both `/usr/include` and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` but now it shows up all these errors... I've successfully compiled a program which uses sfml that runs in linux and a simple (std lib only) program that runs in windows but I can't make this (c++ program that uses sfml) to compile for windows.  Note that my OS is a debian linux distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with SFML itself.

There's something wrong with your cross-compilation environment, since the compiler is mixing files from MinGW (e.g. `/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stdlib.h`) with files from your host system (e.g. `/usr/include/stdlib.h`).

Is there a specific reason you're passing `-I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/`? This is wrong, since those are Linux specific and not the correct ones for MinGW.

You'll have to cross-compile SFML as well and install it somewhere, *not* directly in your regular `/usr/` path, if those are meant to point to SFML.

I'd suggest you install SFML to `/usr/share/mingw-w64`, as this should allow MinGW to pick up the correct files out of the box, without you having to provide paths.

Comment: When I don't write `-I/usr/include` it can't find the SFML directory which is in there. If I only write that one then it requires some other header files which are only located in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` (searched them with `locate` and I found them only in there).

As for cross-compiling SFML... what is that? :P

Comment: I tried making a soft link of SFML dir in both `/usr/share/mingw-w64` and `/usr/share/mingw-w64/include` but it says that it can't find the libraries.

Comment: I had to get the windows version of sfml to make this work (I won't try building it on my one yet :P ) Thanks for the help :D